# What libraries are available for manipulating super large images in .Net

Tags: .net, bitmap, large-files, freeimage

I have some really large files for example 320 MB tif file with 14000 X 9000 pixels.

The operations I need to perform are basically scaling the images to get smaller versions of it and breaking the image into tiles.

My code works fine with small files and I use the .Net `Bitmap` objects but I will occasionally get Out of Memory exceptions for larger files.

I've tried using the FreeImage libraries `FreeImageBitmap` but have the same problems.

I'm using something like the following to scale the image:

```
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage((Image)result))
{
   g.DrawImage(
      source,
      xOffset, yOffset,
      source.Width * scale, source.Height * scale
   );
}
```

Ideally I'd like a third party library to do all the hardwork, but if you have any tips or resources with more information I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 4):

[AForge](http://code.google.com/p/aforge/) is meant to be very good!

Comment: :Could you please tell me is AForge.Net framework supports for loading j2k Images?