# C# Saving huge images

Tags: c#, .net, image, png, large-files

I'm having difficulties when trying to save huge images with C# (I'm talking about over one gigabyte).

Basically I'm trying to do this in parts - I have around 200 bitmap sources and I need a way to combine them before or after encoding them to a .png file.

I know this is going to require lots of RAM unless I somehow stream the data directly from hard drive but I have no idea how to do this either.

Each bitmap source is 895x895 pixels so combining the images after encoding doesn't seem easy because C# doesn't let you create a bitmap with size of 13425 x 13425.

Comment: You could look at [AForge](http://code.google.com/p/aforge/), as recommended by [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/538746/what-libraries-are-available-for-manipulating-super-large-images-in-net?rq=1)'s answer

Comment: That is certainly pushing the limits of what Window's GDI+ can do. You may have to go 3rd party here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This [PngCs library](http://code.google.com/p/pngcs/) (disclaimer: I'm the author) lets you read and write huge PNG images line by line, so that you don't need to keep the full image in memory; perhaps you find it useful.